# How would you set the Cascade on removal?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having some issues while deleting some objects, because those objects have other objects related to them.

For example. I've an entity named `Home`. This entity has some fields like `name` and `description`, aswel as `id`.

And then, I've an entity named `Citizen` which contains `name`, `surname`, `home`. This last field is directly related to Home.

So if I try to remove a HOME object, it crashes because there are some foreign key relating this object. What I'm doing at the moment, is searching for Citizens, and removing them, but this is not the best way to achieve this.

I know there's an annotation like "CASCADE" but I don't know where to place this annotation.

Where do I've to set this annotation to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two ways of achieving your goal. You can use ORM level and Database level cascades.

**ORM Level**

```
// Home Entity

/**
 * @comment The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of ManyToOne
 * 
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Citizen", inversedBy="home", cascade={"remove"})
 */
 protected $citizens;

 // ...
```

**Database Level**

```
// Home Entity

/**
 * onDelete="CASCADE" is used on the joinColumn 
 * It will add On Delete Cascade to the foreign key column in the database.
 * 
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Citizen", inversedBy="home", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="citizen_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
 protected $citizens;

 // ...
```

**Attention**

You have to be careful where you set your cascade option.

You most likely don't want to have doctrine remove your owning side of the relation ( in this case delete the Home if you remove a citizen - therefore only set it on your Home entity ).

Alesh's example is **wrong** in your use case as mappedBy is always the inverse side of a relationship!

In your case Home will be the owning side as one Home will own multiple Citizens.
Now if you delete Home you want your Citizens to be homeless ( aka removed ).

Doctrine also only tracks the owning side of the relation for changes, now if you add a citizen to the collection ( for example with a collection form type ) with ...

```
$home->addCitizen($citizen);
```

... you likely want your citizen to be automatically persisted ( with cascade persist set ) when calling

```
$em->flush();
```

Comment: You misinterpret cascade option. If cascade={"remove"} is @ inversedSide, it tell to remove this association if owning side is removed and not the opposite!

Comment: exactly thats why i put it on the owning side in my example ... mappedBy is always the INVERSE side and inversedBy is always the OWNING side. Read more here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html.

Comment: So the part where you say "alesh's example is wrong" is only a matter of relationship and not a matter of cascading option? If so, I misinterpret you :)

Comment: Thats why i added "in your case" - he wants the citizens to be removed them he removes home, which makes home the owning side and in Alesh's answer it is the inverse side ( mappedBy ). So yes it's only a matter of the wrong relationship :)

Comment: so I misinterpret .... btw I know that mappedBy is always the INVERSED side of the relation

Comment: whoever invented this syntax ... i think it's the one thing most new doctrine users have problems with :D

Answer (score 3):

In your home entity, you should have field, which contains all citizens.

```
    /**
     *
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Citizen", mappedBy="home", cascade={"remove"})
     */
     protected $citizens;
```